# Querying with .toArray won't return any results to view

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Trying to return all the 'titles' of the news. It is not returning anything to frontend. What's the problem?

```
var table = [];

router.get('/api/v1/news', function (req, res) {

   var title = req.params.title;

   News.find({title: title}).toArray(function (err, news) {

      if (err) {
          res.send('error');
      } else if (news.length > 0){

          //table.push(news);
          News.on('row', function (row) {
              table.push(row);
          });

          // After all data is returned, close connection and return results
          News.on('end', function () {
              done();
              return res.json(table);
          });
      }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:**

Okay, it does NOT return any values. This is how it looks in database:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "592142b13257303488922eb2"
    },
    "date": "21-05-2017",
    "text": "noniin",
    "title": "moi",
    "__v": 0
},

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "59217776697b07245cc7d87f"
    },
    "date": "21-05-2017",
    "text": "hgggg",
    "title": "thghfg",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Collection name is News. I can get all data out without specifying to query 'title', but with it, nothing.

Am I understanding req.params wrong? News collection -> find from inside the collection, all 'titles'and return them to view.

Comment: Are you getting value in title = req.params.title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're confusing `req.params` with `req.query`. 
If your request URL is of the form -

```
http://host/api/v1/news?title=something
```

Then the value of title will be available in `req.query.title`.

Otherwise if it's of the form -

```
http://host/api/v1/news/:title
```

Then the value of title will be available in `req.params.title`.

Comment: Thank you. Can you give me example, how i do the "get call" to receive all the news "titles"?(I don't want to get any other information; "text", "date" etc.)

Comment: Then specify which all parameters you want like this in your query - `News.find({title: title}, {title: 1})`. More info [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/).

Answer (score 0):

Try with below solution and pass the parameter in body,

```
    router.get('/api/v1/news', function (req, res) {
    var title = req.body.title;
  return News.find({title : title},function (err, title) {
    if (!err) {
      return res.json({ status: 200, message: "success", data: title});
    }
    else {
      return res.json({ status: 500, message: "failure" });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: you can use above method too, but pass parameter in body and make small change in code. replace  req.params.title with req.body.title

Answer (score 0):

you should change the **/api/v1/news** to **/api/v1/news/:title**

```
var table = [];

router.get('/api/v1/news/:title', function(req, res) {

    var title = req.params.title;

    News.find({
        title: title
    }).toArray(function(err, news) {

        if (err) {
            res.send('error');
        } else if (news.length > 0) {

            News.on('row', function(row) {
                table.push(row);
            });

            News.on('end', function() {
                done();
                return res.json(table);
            });
        }
    });
});
```